# Ruby Multi-part Form Upload with RestClient

Tags: ruby, curl, oauth, rest-client, box-api

I'm working on a ruby application, and am trying to upload a file to box.net.  I have it working with the curl call

```
curl https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/data -H "Authorization: BoxAuth api_key=<API_KEY>&auth_token=<AUTH_TOKEN>" -F folder_id=0 -F filename=@test.txt --trace ~/Desktop/log.txt
```

I've tried to translate this into ruby, and have tried the following

```
request = RestClient::Request.new(:method => :post,:url => "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/data",:authorization => "BoxAuth api_key=<API_KEY>&auth_token=<AUTH_TOKEN>",:filename => "test.txt", :payload => { :multipart => true, :file => File.new("test.txt"))
request.execute
```

but I keep getting back a "401: Unauthorized" response.  I've also tried using the box-api gem, but that seems to only work with version 1.0 of the API, and I'm trying to interface with 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `:headers => {:authorization => "BoxAuth api_key=<API_KEY>&auth_token=<AUTH_TOKEN>"}` in the call. That should fix the missing authorization header.

Complete request would then be:

```
request = RestClient::Request.new(:method => :post,:url => "https://www.box.com/api/2.0/files/data",:headers => {:authorization => "BoxAuth api_key=<API_KEY>&auth_token=<AUTH_TOKEN>"},:filename => "test.txt", :payload => { :multipart => true, :file => File.new("test.txt")})
```

Comment: That did it! I also had to add `:folder_id => "0"` to the payload, but it works. Thanks!